# How can I wake my Canon EOS 1100D up from computer?

Tags: tethering, canon-1100d, programming

I have a Canon EOS 1100D camera and control it by my C# program that use it's tethering feature ‎with Canon EOS Utility dlls.
I have to shoot one photo every 30 minute all day long, but if I want to send the camera into standby ‎mode between two shots, the camera will be disconnected from my computer and I have to power it ‎on by pressing a key on it.

Is there any way that I can reconnect my camera programmatically?

‎

Note: I'm afraid of keeping the camera ON always.‎

Comment: What makes you "afraid" of keeping the camera always on?

Comment: I'm a programmer and quite beginner in working with cameras.  I think it might damage the sensor.

Comment: What evidence do you have it might damage the sensor? It *might* cause the world to implode in a black hole, but I wouldn't worry about that unless there's some evidence it could.

Comment: So you tell me the camera has no problem with being always ON. Am I right?

Comment: The camera will not be damaged by being on.  You might run out of battery though - consider looking into a power adapter.

Answer (score 2):

No, if it isn't detected as being attached, then there wouldn't be any way to communicate with it since it is effectively not plugged in.

Comment: I woke up the camera with a remote shutter; but my program still can't recognize it and crash.